# Where is my partial name getting cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml, partials

I am trying to do some refactoring but am not able to move my partial without getting a missing template error from the calling template.  I renamed and moved the partial, then in the calling template, I changed from:

```
= render 'slot_fields', f: builder
```

To:

```
= render 'slots/slot_create_fields', f: builder
```

But I get the error:

```
Missing partial sheets/_slot_fields, application/_slot_fields
```

I have tried restarting the Rails server and cntl-F5 to reload the page but I am stuck.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to "_slot_fields" with the underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help but I just figured it out.  I was referring to the `partial` somewhere else (a `link_to` helper).

Answer (score 0):

Rails templates are not cached by default.
It could be possible that your templates get precompiled by the Rails Asset Pipeline.
Try to clean all the precompiled assets with the following

`rake assets:clobber`